# TextStyle exists in React-native library but flow says is missing?

Tags: react-native

I'm working on the code below, once I add Text style property `lineHeight: 1` then Flow type-checking tool gives a red marker which says:

**"Cannot create `View` element because property `lineHeight` is missing in  object type [1] but exists in  object literal [2] in property `style`.Flow(InferError)"**

How to solve this error? By the way error don't come one I remove 'lineHeight:1' which is pointless if removed and not my intentions.

```
//Imports with Destructuring
// @flow

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

//Prepare the contents
const Header = (props) => {
    //Destructuring the styles
    const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <View style={viewStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{props.headerText}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

//Style the contents
const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',

        lineHeight:3,
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 50,
        paddingTop: 15,
        position: 'relative'
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize: 30,
        color: '#3D407B',
        fontWeight:'bold',

        borderRadius: 3,
        borderStyle:'solid',

    },

    myStyle: {


    }
};

//Make them available to the app
export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2):

`lineHeight` supported in Text not in View.